# When was the "New Kingdom" of Egypt first called that?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-egypt, etymology, toponymy

When was the New Kingdom of Egypt (c. 1550BC to 1077BC) first called "New Kingdom" (or something cognate)?

Comment: Reasonable amount of online searching, mainly in Google Books. But nothing more than that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the *Oxford Companion to Archaeology*, the term [*New Kingdom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Kingdom_of_Egypt) was introduced by the German historian [Eduard Meyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Meyer) in his *Geschichte des Altertums*. English Egyptologists adopted his usage, displacing their earlier designation of the period as the "*Empire*".

<sub>**Source:** Silberman, Neil Asher, and Alexander A. Bauer, eds. *The Oxford Companion to Archaeology.* Oxford University Press, 2012.</sub>

---

The division of Egyptian history into [*Old*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Kingdom_of_Egypt) and [*New*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Kingdom_of_Egypt) Kingdoms was pioneered by [Carl Richard Lepsius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Richard_Lepsius). In his 1858 *Königsbuch der alten Ägypter*, Lepsius grouped [Manetho's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manetho) Dynasties under the categories *Alten Reich* and *Neues Reich*, assigning Dynasties XVII to XXXI in the latter. This periodisation seem to have been inspired by [Baron von Bunsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Charles_Josias_von_Bunsen)'s work in the 1830s or 40s.

I'm not sure why the *Oxford Companion to Archaeology* chose to credit Meyer over Lepsius here.

Answer (score 4):

According to this:

http://www.bibelwissenschaft.de/wibilex/das-bibellexikon/lexikon/sachwort/anzeigen/details/neues-reich-3/ch/746c4a4853fde241e7777581bf2e29c9/

the designation “Neues Reich” was in use since 1834. This was about 20 years before the birth of Eduard Meyer.

Comment: The fact that Reich is usually translated as Empire might complicate the issue a bit.

Comment: I don't see any complication. Meyer also used "Neues Reich".

Answer (score 1):

The first publication I know of was by Christian Charles Josias, the Baron von Bunsen, in his *Aegyptens Stelle in der Weltgeschichte* (1845). This was the publication that brought the classification into general use among English-speaking Egyptologists. To quote from Browne's *Hierogrammata*:

> The tract of time from Menes downward is divided by M. Bunsen and
>   Lepsius, into three portions, which they designate by the names, Old,
>   Middle, and New Kingdom. The first of these ends at or shortly after
>   the close of the great Diospolitan Dynasty of the Osortasens, or
>   Sesortesens and Amenemhes, which in Manetho is the Twelfth Dynasty.
>   The third, or New Kingdom, begins with the Diospolitan Dynasty of
>   Amosis, which is Manetho's Eighteenth. The intermediate period, that
>   of the Middle Kingdom, is the time of the usurped dominion of the
>   Hyksos or Shepherd-Kings.
>
> The epoch of the New Kingdom is placed by M. Bunsen at 1688 B.C. The
>   grounds on which this determination rests will be fully examined in
>   the Second Chapter of this Work, where it will be shewn, by monumental
>   and documentary evidence, that the Eighteenth Dynasty began about
>   fourteen Centuries, only, before Christ.